# How to get cisco sh version command-like snmp info

Tags: snmp, cisco

this is my first question here..!!!

I'm triying to develop my own network inventory application by using SNMP traps.

My problem is I can't find out how to get interfaces information from cisco devices, like *show version* IOS command do. ie:

```
Cisco CISCO2911/K9 (revision 1.0) with 487424K/36864K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID FJC1914A05A
3 Gigabit Ethernet interfaces
1 terminal line
1 Virtual Private Network (VPN) Module
```

What OID can I use to get this information or  same in an analog way..?

Best Regards,

Valle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the version of IOS you need to use the following OID: `1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.25.1.1.1.2.7`

You can also use `1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 (sysDecr)` from system group of MIB-II.

Other parameters you can get from different MIBs:

- Interfaces from `IF-MIB` or `RFC1213::ifTable`
- Boards from `ENTITY-MIB`

Comment: Very useful. I use your recommendation and expand form OID '1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.25.1.1.1.2.1'  to   '1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.25.1.1.1.2.9'.

Comment: But I can't find how to obtain a resume of interfaces

Comment: You should fetch `ifTable` for interfaces. It is a part of `RFC1213`

Answer (score -1):

use the "show cdp neighbors" or "show cdp neighbors detail" to have information about cisco devices